# Primitive roots of unity in Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, complex-numbers, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Why do primitive roots of unity show up and are used in proofs in the context of Galois theory? I refer for example to chapter 8.8 of Ian Stewart's "Galois theory" and to John Stillwell's paper "Galois theory for beginners".

- I quote "Theorem 2" of Stillwell's paper. If $E \supseteq B(\alpha)
     \supseteq B$ are fields with $\alpha^p \in B$ for some prime $p$, and
  if $B(\alpha)$ contains no $p$th roots of unity not in $B$ unless
  $\alpha$ itself is a $p$th root of unity, then $Gal(E/B(\alpha))$ is
  a normal subgroup of $Gal(E/B)$ and $Gal(E/B)/Gal(E/B(\alpha))$ is
  abelian.
- In Ian Stewart's book instead the primitive roots of unity first show up in the proof of the so-called "Natural Irrationalities" theorem. A technical lemma says that if $M$ is a subfield of $L$ containing the field $K$ and $\alpha \in M$ with $\alpha$ not a $p$th power in $M$, then the polynomial $m(x) = x^p-\alpha$ is irreducible over $M$. I can follow the logical steps of the proof but the use of primitive roots of unity is unexpected to me.

Comment: Please, include your examples either as a link (and I don't mean a paper, I mean a paragraph), or write them down. Not everybody has access to these right away. Even if they do, they might have the energy to look these up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  The roots of unity arise quite naturally in this case.  Say that you have the polynomial $x^p-a$, and that it's irreducible (basically $a$ is not a $p^{th}$ root in the ground field) and separable.  Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^p-a$.  What will the other roots be?

> $\alpha \zeta^k$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $p^{th}$ root of unity and $1\leq k\leq p-1$.  So the splitting fields of the polynomials $x^p-a$ are connected to the $p^{th}$ roots of unity.  Hence their appearance in the Galois Theory results you mention.