# Understanding Automorphism in Galois for Beginners by John Stillwell

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

I am having trouble to understand automorphism in the article "[Galois for beginners](http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Esmahanta/Teaching/Spring10/Stillwell.pdf)" by John Stillwell, like my friend  [Leo's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2440452/613063) and [Alberto's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2375147/613063). The main  question is related to the automorphism described in theorem 2, but instead of one question, I am breaking it down so the it becomes easy to answer.

First I state the questions, the complete proof is given below.

**a.** What does $\sigma'\sigma|_{B(\alpha)}=\sigma'|_{B(\alpha)}\sigma|_{B(\alpha)}$  mean in below proof?

**b.** Does   $\sigma'\sigma|_{B(\alpha)}(\beta)=\sigma'|_{B(\alpha)}(\beta)\sigma|_{B(\alpha)}(\beta)$?

**c.** Why we need $\sigma'\sigma|_{B(\alpha)}=\sigma'|_{B(\alpha)}\sigma|_{B(\alpha)}$ in the proof?

**d.** In the proof, it is written that, if $\alpha$ is a pth root of unity $\zeta$ then $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^i$ but according to the fact that $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(E/B(\alpha))$, it should be $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$, so why $\sigma$ is not fixing $\alpha$?

Note, $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(E/B(\alpha)) \implies \sigma \in \text{Gal}(E/B)$ because $B(\alpha) \supset B$, if $\sigma$ fixes $B(\alpha)$ it also fixes $B$, since it fixes  $B(\alpha)$, so $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$, by the definition. This also makes the below line found in the proof ***redundant***-

> $\sigma|_{B(\alpha)}$ is completely determined by the value
> $\sigma(\alpha)$.

because by the definition, $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$.

**e.** If $\alpha$ is a pth root of unity $\zeta$ then $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^i$ according to author, **but why not** $\sigma(\alpha)=a\zeta^i+b$ where $a,b \in B$, note, $a\zeta^i+b$ still $ \in B(\alpha)$, so $\sigma$ is remains an automorphism of $E$.

**f.** If $\alpha$ **is not a pth root of unity**, why $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha \zeta^i$  for some pth root of unity $\zeta$?

**g.** Using the similar argument in e.,  why not $\sigma(\alpha)=a\zeta^i+b$ instead of $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha \zeta^i$  for some pth root of unity $\zeta$, when  $\alpha$ **is not a pth root of unity**,?

See the proof given below-

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: $\sigma'|_{B(\alpha)}\sigma|_{B(\alpha)}$ denotes the composition of $\sigma'|_{B(\alpha)}$ and $\sigma|_{B(\alpha)}$. We need the equality so that we can define a homomorphism.

Comment: It is inconsiderate of you to delete a question on which people have been working, and post another question that is a duplicate of the one you deleted. I shall flag this question for moderator attention. (Perhaps they will restore the deleted question. I don't know how such problems are handled.)

Comment: @calum sorry but I didn't know,  I was having difficulty to edit probably due to server issue, so I rewrote. Also plz rewrite ur answer here.

Comment: I hadn't written an answer. I was going to, but Nelli Kuukeri's answer here (+1) covers all the points I had in mind, and more. I hope the moderators will find some way to amalgamate the two versions of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. It means you take the restrictions of $\sigma, \sigma'$ and of their composite. The composite of the restrictions is claimed (by that equation) to be the same as the restriction of the composite.

b. No, the "product" $\sigma'\sigma$ means their composite, not the function $x\mapsto\sigma'(x)\cdot\sigma(x)$.

c. As Thomas said, to get the homomorphism.

d. It is not assumed that $\sigma$ fixes $B(\alpha)$.

e. If $b\neq0$ and $\sigma(\alpha^p)=\sigma(\alpha)^p=(a\zeta^i+b)^p=1$, then $b$ will actually turn out to be of the form $c\zeta^j$ for suitable $c, j$ that will make $a\zeta^i+b=a\xi^k$ for a root $\xi$ of unity.

f. $\alpha^p\in B$, so $\sigma(\alpha^p)=\alpha^p$. Since we may choose $b=0$, $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha\cdot z$ for some $z$ with the property $z^p=1$.

Comment: You have not understood e properly, about d, read the last line of the frist paragraph of the proof, it is assumed as I wrote.

Comment: Where? I can't see it.

Comment: See in the same line of  sentence ''... is the identity map''

Comment: If you mean the iff-thingy, that is just that $\sigma$ fixes $B(\alpha)$ iff the restriction is the identity. It has nothing to do with assuming that $\sigma$ fixes the extension.

Comment: From $(a\zeta^i+b)^p=1$ i guess you assume that $(a\zeta^i+b)$ is pth roots of unity, but why do u think $(a\zeta^i+b)$ is pth roots of unity? it might not be... all i said is  $\sigma(\alpha)=(a\zeta^i+b)$, clearly $\sigma$ maps $E$ to $E$ when  $\sigma(\alpha)=(a\zeta^i+b)$... but it does not tell $(a\zeta^i+b)$ is pth roots of unity when  $\sigma(\alpha)=(a\zeta^i+b)$

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a $p$th root of unity and $\sigma$ is a field homomorphism, then $\sigma(\alpha^p)=1$.

Comment: Aha..yes, btw, can you provide an example using argument for point 1, 2 to be clear? so it could be understood why they need to write those function in that way, an explicit example will clarify.

Comment: Let's be boring and have 2 bijections from $\{1, 2, 3\}$ to itself. Let $f, g$ be given by $f(1)=1, f(2)=3$ and $g(1)=2, g(2)=1$, and let's have $B=\{ 1, 2\}$. Now, $(f\circ g)|_B$ sends $1$ to $3$ and $2$ to $1$, and the composite $f|_B\circ g|_B$ is the same, but the same thing is not true if you change their order, as the composite of the restrictions is not even defined ($f(2)\not\in B$). That is why you need to check that. The second thing is just notation, note that the automorphisms give you a group, so the author wrote composition down as a product.